# Circle CI and Gradle Deamon

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, circleci, gradlew

Project Build fails in CircleCI, after Gradle Update

- Previous Gradle Version  **3.3**
- Updated Gradle Version **4.3.1**

I get a Circle error [Heap error]

**Error Message:**

```
21231 1656884 155 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp /home/ubuntu/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.3.1-all/97nfwr7im082t7xwc6bkwfrg9/gradle-4.3.1/lib/gradle-launcher-4.3.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 4.3.1*
```

I thought the problem with Gradle deamon. I turn off the deamon, but it is still not working.

```yaml
machine:
  environment:
    GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"
this:

  build:
    branch: /.*/
    commands:
      - ./gradlew testStagingDebugUnitTest --no-daemon
      - (./gradlew assembleDebug --no-daemon):
          timeout: 900
```

In `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.daemon=false
```

Comment: You might be running out of memory, but it is going to be extremely difficult to tell without any logs from build.

Comment: Try to tune your `-Xmx` to see if it works. `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2000m`